# Elasticsearch Aggregation Query Builder

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5, elasticsearch-aggregation

I am new to working with aggregations in Elasticsearch. I am on version 5.3 of Elasticsearch. I have a query to do a terms aggregation and also a filter, but when I try to use `AggregationsBuilder` to build the same query, I can't get it to look the same as the manual query. The manual query works and it is:

```
{
    "size": 0,
    "aggs": {
        "data": {
            "nested": {
                "path": "data"
            },
            "aggs": {
                "my_filters": {
                    "filter": {
                        "bool": {
                            "must": [
                                {
                                    "term": {
                                        "data.genre": "sci-fi"
                                    }
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    },
                    "aggs": {
                        "my_agg_field": {
                            "terms": {
                                "field": "data.director.keyword"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But in my code, I need to use `AggregationBuilder` to create the query. So I use the following:

```
        AggregationBuilder aggregation =
              AggregationBuilders
                    .nested("data", "data")
                    .subAggregation(
                          AggregationBuilders.filter("filters", query)
                                .subAggregation(
                                      AggregationBuilders
                                            .terms("bucket_field").field("data.directors.keyword")
                                )
                    );
```

With the `AggregationsBuilder`, I get the following query:

```
{
"aggs": {
  "filters" : {
    "filter" : {
      "nested" : {
        "query" : {
          "bool" : {
            "must" : [
              {
                "match" : {
                  "data.genre" : {
                    "query" : "sci-fi",
                    "operator" : "OR"
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        "path" : "data"
      }
    },
    "aggregations" : {
      "bucket_field" : {
        "terms" : {
          "field" : "data.director.keyword"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
}
```

This aggregation query returns results but doesn't aggregate the buckets like the manual query does and just returns:

```
    "aggregations": {
        "filters": {
            "doc_count": 62,
            "bucket_field": {
                "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
                "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
                "buckets": []
            }
        }
    },
```

I need help converting my manual query into an `AggregationsBuilder` query. Thanks!